# Can't access member sync page

Tags: wordpress, civimail

My wordpress site is hosted by godaddy and I want to use CiviCRM but when I click here:  CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync   the settings link it says this: "Sorry you are not allowed to access this page".  Hence, I can't set up the member info, etc. 
Wendy

Comment: If you don't have the correct permissions, you won't be able to access the plugin's Settings page. Ask your WordPress admin for a role that has the `manage_options` capability first.